# How could i make my .json files read-write except read-only?

Tags: post, next.js, vercel, read-write

I made a website with next.js and deploy it with vercel. When i tried to make post action to my api's i take that error:

```
2023-02-17T00:54:35.670Z    94b0f453-0bfc-486b-ab0a-d36c86b0e9c4    ERROR   Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/var/task/public/database/azalar.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:600:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2221:35)
    at handler (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/auth/register.js:106:50)
    at Object.apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:372:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async NextNodeServer.runApi (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:488:9)
    at async Object.fn (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:751:37)
    at async Router.execute (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:253:36)
    at async NextNodeServer.run (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:384:29)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleRequest (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:322:20) {
  errno: -30,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EROFS',
  path: '/var/task/public/database/azalar.json'
}
```

after a research i learn it causes from that files are read-only and i don't know how to change that.

i try to solve this problem with allowing somethings on github repository but honestly i don't understand nor could. I set settings such that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrvPf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ggzs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIo1R.png)

So how can i make my .json files to read-write? And how should i set these values?

Comment: The dist files of a build should be left read-only, making them writable is almost never a good approach. That JSON file managed by the NextJS build process will be overwritten with its checked-in defaults for every build, which it sounds like you wouldn't want. For data you want to be mutable, you should be using either a database, setState/useState, or localStorage, depending on your use-case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I solved my problem with modifying my api's for cloud firestore. thanks for the answer though. If